# Getting data from AWS DynamoDB in chunks

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

I get specific data from DynamodDB with Lambda (node.js) and send it to android app. The problem is that I don't want to send every data which satisfy my condition in Node.js in one go. I view those data in list-view in my android app. In my DB there might be milions of records and it could take really long time to get all those data. I am thinking about the efficient way of sendig those data. My idea is to send only first (for example) 20 records, when the user scroll down the list send request to server with last record's ID, look through the DB and send another 20 records to app. Is there any better way to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The amazon APIs for dynamoDB allows you to restrict the number of results you fetch in GET and SCAN operations.

The javascript sdk allows you to specify `Limit`.
The API returns LastEvaluatedKey which will allow you to retrieve further results.

Pass the LastEvaluatedKey value as ExclusiveStartKey when you make the next request.

Since Lambda is stateless, you will have to pass the LastEvaluatedKey back to the client and pass it back to the function when next retrieval is needed.

Reference doc:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#query-property
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#scan-property